# PIL's Image.frombuffer creates wrong image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create an image from 1d `numpy` array of integers so that changes to this array reflects in the image. It seems that `Image.frombuffer` perfectly fits my needs. There's my attempts:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = np.full(100, 255, dtype = np.int32)
img = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (10, 10), data)
print(list(img.getdata()))
```

I expected to see a list of 100 tuples `(0, 0, 255)`. But what I'm actually getting is `(0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), ...`

What is the reason of that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'RGB'` uses three bytes per pixel.  The buffer that you provided is an array with data type `numpy.int32`, which uses four bytes per element.  So you have a mismatch.

One way to handle it is to use mode `'RGBA'`:

```
img = Image.frombuffer('RGBA', (10, 10), data)
```

Whether or not that is a good solution depends on what you are going to do with the image.

Also note that whether you get (255, 0, 0, 0) or (0, 0, 0, 255) for the RGBA pixels depends on the [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the integers in `data`.

For an RGB image, here's an alternative:

```
data = np.zeros(300, dtype=np.uint8)
# Set the blue channel to 255.
data[2::3] = 255
img = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (10, 10), data)
```

Without more context for the problem, I don't know if that is useful for you.

Comment: Aha, why there is no `int24` type. OK, it works with `RGBA`. I'm going to draw this image on the user's screen in some way.